# Updates in Forge .net api

Tags: autodesk-forge

Will functionality for manifest and webhooks be available in the .Net api soon?
This would be really appriciated to avoid using rest calls.

Regards
Øyvind Knappskog Olsen

Comment: Forge APIs is a set of REST API, you can use any REST client tools written in any programming language (e.g. .NET, Go, Python, Node.js) to interact with Forge APIs. So, there is no .NET API. I think you are asking something related to Forge dot NET SDK, don't you?

Comment: And what is the `manifest` in your question? Did you check these two methods?
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/DerivativesApi.md#getmanifest and https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/DerivativesApi.md#getderivativemanifest

Comment: Could you help me check the question above? So that, I ask the project owner if there is a plan. Thanks!